# trading-vue-js модальное окно

Tags: javascript, css, html5

https://github.com/tvjsx/trading-vue-js/

Я сделал график. есть оверлей модалка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как это вызвать при нажатии на кастомную кнопку? Это модальное окно появляется, когда вы нажимаете + в оверлее, но графік может не всегда иметь оверлей. Соответственно нет этой кнопки. Было решено добавить кастомную кнопку, которая будет вызывать этот модал. но как это сделать???